# Batch Renaming part of a file name in docs command line using REN

Tags: cmd, command-line, file-rename

Trying to figure out how to batch rename part of a filename in doc command line using 'ren'.

My filenames: 
abc_124_xyz_202112**2**345_123.txt
abc_124_xyz_202112**2**346_124.txt
abc_124_xyz_202112**2**347_125.txt

How do I get rid of the extra '2' (highlighted in bold above)

I tried using '?': 
ren abc_124_xyz_20211?234?-???.txt abc_124_xyz_20211234?-???.txt
and
also tried using '*' in place of ???
neither worked.
For some reason underscore appears as a italicized ?. So I used hyphen.
See attached screenshot, which has underscore.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using powershell: 
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '2021122', '202112' }

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know windows is not able to do this smart kind of rename `abc$1def$2ghi.txt` to `abcdef$2ghi.txt` that you want (get rid of the first field).

Anyway, maybe a more generic single wildcard rename would work:

First, check if nothing more than expected is included:

```
dir abc_124_xyz_202112????????.txt
```

If it's ok, then run:

```
ren abc_124_xyz_202112????????.txt abc_124_xyz_20211????????.txt
```

If it is not ok, you can (1) move the files to an external folder to rename them in isolation or (2) build a renamer script that filter out the specific files and rename one by one, by a substring version that skips the 17th character:

1. Auxiliar folder approach:

```
md rentemp
move abc_124_xyz_20211?234?_???.txt rentemp
ren rentemp\abc_124_xyz_202112????????.txt abc_124_xyz_20211????????.txt
move rentemp\* .
rd rentemp
```

2. Auxiliar script approach:

```
for %f in ("abc_124_xyz_20211?234?_???.txt") do (
 set n=%f
 echo ren %n% %n:~0,17%%n:~18% >> renamer.bat
)
```

Then run `renamer.bat`

We need the renamer.bat because if we rename the own file which is used in the loop, the loop itself breaks, so the script below does not work:

```
for %f in ("abc_124_xyz_20211?234?_???.txt") do (
 set n=%f
 ren %n% %n:~0,17%%n:~18%
)
```

Comment: Another way of looking at this is just deleting nth character in the file name. Can ren do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer using your approach